# AWS EC2 instance having multiple addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible for my AWS instance to have multiple public IPs? I already tried associating Elastic IP but.. When I went inside my server and executed `curl ifconfig.me`, it only returns 1 IP address

Comment: You can add multiple ENI’s and associate unique public IP’s to each one.

Comment: Oh, I am an AWS newbie. I need to check this ENI. Do you have a good documentation link or reference for what I need?

Comment: This might help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html

Comment: You can have multiple interfaces. I think if you route to the Internet, you only use 1 interface.

Comment: Oh I need to have multiple IPs as in when I do `curl ifconfig.me`, it will return multiple IPs.. The real use-case here is to avoid the Request Per Second per IP on a particular API

Comment: You can have multiple IP addresses for a single node, but you can not use multiple IP addresses for a single TCP connection

Comment: @jordanm so what I want is impossible?

Comment: I suspect you're looking for something like this: https://github.com/Ge0rg3/requests-ip-rotator

Comment: Yes, that.. But I would like to avoid a network hop as much as possible. Using API Gateway is a network hop

Comment: So is using the internet gateway through ec2. Are you worried about 0-5ms of additional latency?

Comment: @jordanm, I guess I should not.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach several ENIs to a single machine.

Each ENI can also have several IP v4 addresses, and for each of them you can attach one Elastic IP.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html

Different ENIs are seen on the host as different network cards, so you will need to explicitly route the traffic to one or another to see the public IP changing on `ifconfig.me`

Comment: Okay let me try.

Comment: How to know if i am successful? Do you have like a blog or reference that I can follow?

Comment: For your operating system, look on how you can modify the route table. Once done, you will be able to see.
Other solution, try to attach using `netcat` to one private IP address with a given port on the machine and from another one try to contact (still using `nc`) the ElasticIP corresponding to this private IP address, and then do with others.